# Трещотка и чечетка (танец, а не птица)

Tags: орфография

Интересно, чем объясняется разница в написании этих слов, ведь в обоих словах - гласная под ударением после шипящих. Правила известны: в корне "ё", если есть проверочное слово с буквой "е", а в суффиксе - "о", если это суффикс существительного, прилагательного или наречия, и "ё" - в суффиксах отглагольных форм. Разве "трещотка" не от глагола "трещать"?

Посмотрел я ссылку и разочаровался: там столько путаницы, а главное - много предлагается запоминать. Не знаю, прав ли я, но когда-то в своем пособии для поступающих я это правило записывал предельно кратко: "В КОРНЕ СЛОВА ПОСЛЕ ШИПЯЩИХ ПОД УДАРЕНИЕМ ПИШЕТСЯ "Ё", ЕСЛИ МОЖНО ПОДОБРАТЬ ПРОВЕРОЧНОЕ СЛОВО, В КОТОРОМ ПИШЕТСЯ "Е" НА ЭТОМ МЕСТЕ". При этом не надо запоминать никакие "крыжовники, шорохи,капюшоны..." Все просто. А В СУФФИКСАХ И ОКОНЧАНИЯХ ИМЕН (сущ., прилаг.)И НАРЕЧИЙ ПИШЕТСЯ ПОД УДАРЕНИЕМ "О", ЗАТО В ОТГЛАГОЛЬНЫХ ФОРМАХ - "Ё". Мой вопрос и был навеян некоторой несостыковкой относительно слова "трещотка", так как я считал, что оно образовано от глагола "трещать". Уважаемый "b..." убедил меня, что, скорее всего, исходным было слово "треск". Если я правильно применил остаточные знания по исторической грамматике, то процесс там шел по такой цепочке: треск`отка - тресч`отка - трещотка.  Вот таковы мои примитивные размышлизмы. Буду рад, если покритикуете старика.

Comment: Все у вас верно. Кстати, это верное правило вернулось в школьные учебники. Запоминать приходится гораздо меньше. Но надо сказать, что при небольшом словарном запасе многим все-таки легче запомнить, чем подобрать однокоренные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Разве "трещотка" не от глагола "трещать"?

Нет. От слова "треск" напрямую. Этим и объясняется О в суффиксе. Преход Щ<СК - вообще довольно частный случай в руссом.

А вообще этот случай обычно оговаривается в списке исключений.

*Примечание 3. Следует запомнить написание слов с затемнённым составом или непродуктивными суффиксами, где о или е пишется по традиции: а) крыжовник, трущоба, чащоба, трещотка; б) учёба (ср. учение), решётка (ср. решето), бечёвка (ср. бечева), дешёвый (ср. де­шевле).*
[Гласные после шипящих и Ц в корне слова | rustest.edu.ru](http://rustest.edu.ru/rules/orfografia/korni/3139/)

ЗЫ Насчет "орфограмы с суффиксом -отк-" - не понял. Странное объяснение. Есть же масса слов с суффиксом "етк". Вагонетка, например. И тоже под кдарение. Я понимаю, суффиксы разного происхождения, но как разобраться-то, не зная ответа наперед? Считайте уж лучше словарным.

Comment: Да, когда не знаешь, как пишется слово, тогда к словарю, а когда задан прямой вопрос "чем объясняется разница в написании этих слов", тогда объясняешь, не используя специфических терминов (здесь я имею в виду "морфологический принцип орфографии"), по-простому. И еще, слово "трещотка" образовано от глагола "трещать", см. словообразовательный словарь Тихонова, но не электронный, а настоящий, печатный.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Я говорил о том, что правило у вас сформулировано неадекватано задаче, которую призвано решать. Да, если знаешь, как пишется, правило не нужно. А есди не знаешь, то ваш вариант не поможет. Всё -отк- суффиксы имеют под уларением О. А суффикссы -ётк- - Ё. Вопрос, как выбрать.

У меня нет бумажного Тихова. Мне застерлиться?    
В любом случае он использует "школьный" синхонистичекий подход. А тут изначально идет речь о историческом происхождении, который и объясняет орфографию.

Comment: Оно и понятно, что "ничего не понял".

Comment: Ну вот и вы что-то поняли.

Answer (score 5):

1. ЧЕЧЁТКА, Небольшая певчая птица сем. вьюрковых  Её голос — повторяющееся ритмическое «че-че», «че-че-че», «чень», «чееии»
2. ЧЕЧЁТКА -чёткий по ритму, быстрый танец с частым и дробным пристукиванием подошвы и каблука об пол. 
    Это разные значения одного слова, поэтому пишутся одинаково.Чечётка-самка чечета. Отсюда понятно, почему Ё.(фонематический принцип - проверяем чередованием в однокоренных).
   Трещотка - исконно русское слово - инструмент, производящий треск, который трещит: трещ+ суфф. - отк-(-ётк- не было, потому что не было буквы Ё, она появилась только в 1783 году как дифтонг io)- отсюда написание по традиции, хотя теперь суфф. -отк- не выделяется.
   Одно время слово трещётка в значении "тараторка" писали через ё как отглагольное, потом перешли к одинаковому написанию, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: Людмила, спасибо, очень интересная информация.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в написании этих слов объясняется тем, что

(1) в слове *чечетк*а орфограмма в корне (если образовать новое слово — *чечет*, то ударение перейдет на другой (у нас это первый) слог, что является условием выбора буквы *е*, см. Кайдалова, Калинина, Современная русская орфография, § 7);

(2) в слове *трещотка* орфограмма в суффиксе (суффикс *-отк-* всегда находится под ударением, поэтому в нем пишется та буква, которая слышится, ср. крас*о*тка, чес*о*тка, барх*о*тка).

Comment: Друзья, посмотрите, ЧТО я напридумывал в правке вопроса, и покритикуйте меня.

Answer (score 0):

А  от  чего  образовано  слово  "чечётка",  если  это  танец ?  И  если  мы  образуем  слово  чечет,  то  это  птица.  Правда  П.Я. Черных  связывает  происхождение  названия  танца  от  названия  птицы,  но  как-то  неуверенно.  Может  есть  другая  этимология ?

Comment: Правда,  Даль  отмечает  переносное  значение  названия  птицы.  Чечётка - болтливая  женщина,  тараторка.  А  уж  от  этого  значения  до  названия  танца  рукой  подать.